# Laravel Maatwebsite - after export file session gets logout

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner to `Laravel 5.4`. 
I used `maatwebsite/excel` service to export data from database to excel sheet. It's working fine, but one thing happens, after exporting files in excel sheet, my current user session suddenly gets logout.
Then I need to loging again. I don't know why such things happen. Please tell me where I m wrong.

Code
Controller =>

```
public function listOrders(Request $request)
{
    $order = app()->make('Order');
    if ($request->has('export')) {
        $order->exportToExcel($request);
    }
    $orderList = $order->getAllOrderListByConditions($request);

    return view('order::list-orders', $orderList);
}
```

Service = >

```
public function exportToExcel($request)
{
    $details = $this->getAllOrderListByConditions($request);

    $name = $details['hotel']->name . ' ' . date('d-m-Y');
    Excel::create($name, function($excel) use($details, $name) {

        // Set the title
        $excel->setTitle($name);

        // Call them separately
        $excel->setDescription('Order report');

        $excel->sheet($name, function($sheet) use ($details) {
            $sheet->loadView('order::list-orders-excel', $details);
        });

    })->export('xlsx');

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `route` protected by `middleware`? Might be useful if you can give us more information (`routes.php` / `web.php`).

Comment: No , my route is not protected by middleware.

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => '/', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Order\Http\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::resource('order', 'OrderController');
    Route::get('order/list-orders/1', 'OrderController@listOrders')->name('order.list-orders');
});